# Why my reference only shows the latex codes instead of the proper name?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

This is my latex code for the main file:

[image]

and this is the bbl code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
@article{behkam_sitti_2008, title={Effect of quantity and configuration of attached bacteria on 
bacterial propulsion of microbeads}, volume={93}, DOI={10.1063/1.3040318}, number={22}, journal= 
{Applied Physics Letters}, author={Behkam, Bahareh and Sitti, Metin}, year={2008}, month={Dec}, 
pages={223901}} 
\end{thebibliography}
```

Could someone please tell me where went wrong?

Edit: when I get rid of \begin{thebibliography}{} and \end{thebibliography}:

```
@article{behkam_sitti_2008, title={Effect of quantity and configuration of attached bacteria on 
bacterial propulsion of microbeads}, volume={93}, DOI={10.1063/1.3040318}, number={22}, journal= 
{Applied Physics Letters}, author={Behkam, Bahareh and Sitti, Metin}, year={2008}, month={Dec}, 
pages={223901}}
```

what I get is :
[image]

Comment: You're doing it wrong... your "bbl code" should not include the `\begin{bibliography}{}`...`\end{bibliography}` components.

Comment: Hi, I have deleted those two lines in the bib file. But the reference is still not correct. I updated this in the question and could you please have a look?

Comment: The file should be `biophysics.bib`, not `biophysics.bbl`.

Comment: The `.bbl` file is a temporary file that is automatically generated by BibTeX. You should almost never have to modify it manually and you should absolutely not have to create it from scratch. If you want to use `.bib` entries like the one shown in your question in LaTeX, you need to put them into `<filename>.bib` where `<filename>` is the file name you pass to `\bibliography`: `\bibliography{<filename>}` (in your case that would be `biophysics.bib`).

Comment: Thank you! I am feeling so stupid... xp

Answer (score 1):

The `.bbl` file is a temporary file that is automatically generated by BibTeX. You should almost never have to modify it manually and you should absolutely not have to create it from scratch.

If you want to use `.bib` entries like the one shown in your question in LaTeX, you need to put them into `<filename>.bib` where `<filename>` is the file name you pass to `\bibliography`: `\bibliography{<filename>}` (in your case that would be `biophysics.bib`).

When you then run BibTeX, BibTeX will take the entries from your `.bib` file, sorts and formats them according to the `\bibliographstyle` you selected and writes them into a `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` environment to the `.bbl` file. LaTeX then automatically gets the bibliography from the `.bbl` file in the next LaTeX run.

You can find more details about the workings of BibTeX at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Most introductions into LaTeX that explain bibliographies should also explain how to use BibTeX and `.bib` files (e.g. https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-12), but there are also resources specifically about using BibTeX https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex or https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_natbib.